# Subversion command scripts

Tags: svn

i have this command
"TortoiseProc.exe" /command:update /path:"D:\Work_SVN\projectname"/notempfile

to update working copy.

I also have 'svn st -u' to check for modifications from repository.
How to use this command in above syntax.

Bibhu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the command line client for scripting, not a GUI.  You wouldn't script copying files from one directory to another by simulating the mouse clicking and dragging, would you?

Answer (score 1):

Read the [manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html)!

In general, you cannot just execute the status command of SVN with TortoiseProc. However, you can open the repostatus window using `/command:repostatus`.

*(here follows a rephrase from the Manual)*

Remember that TortoiseSVN is a GUI client, and this TortoiseProc allows you to make the TortoiseSVN dialogs appear to collect user input. If you want to write a script which requires no input, you should use the official Subversion command line client instead.

*(rephrase from the Manual ends here... geesh)*

Comment: You should blockquote the passage from the documentation so that it's clear that it's not your words.

Comment: @Michael - it isn't a direct quote.

Comment: Replace "TortoiseProc allows you" with "automation guide shows you how" and the rest is, word-for-word, identical to the second paragraph in the link you included to the documentation!  Maybe it's a coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

You use the `update` subcommand:

```
svn update "D:\Work_SVN\projectname"
```

Type `svn help update` to see all its options and `svn help` to learn about all subcommands.
See also the [svn update chapter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html) in the [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/index.html) book.